# Codes - 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create new table with union,
What is wrong with those codes?

```
insert into chart

select months, field, value from (

select hp.months, 'ActualBookings2014' as field, hp.ActualBookings2014 as value
FROM         hp_metglobal.hp

UNION

select hp.months, 'TargetBookings' as field, hp.TargetBookings as value
FROM        hp_metglobal.hp

UNION

select hp.months, 'ActualBookings2013' as field, hp.ActualBookings2013 as value
FROM         hp_metglobal.hp

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use an alias for inner table:

```
insert into chart

select months, field, value from ((

select hp.months, 
       'ActualBookings2014' as field,
        hp.ActualBookings2014 as value
FROM    hp_metglobal.hp

UNION

select hp.months, 
       'TargetBookings' as field,
        hp.TargetBookings as value
FROM    hp_metglobal.hp

UNION

select  hp.months, 
        'ActualBookings2013' as field,
        hp.ActualBookings2013 as value
FROM    hp_metglobal.hp

) as t)
```